# Serialize method of ajax not returning required values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to get form inputs through ajax j query bootstrap modal and store it into the database but serialize method is not returning all the values required.

It should have returned the values of user_id and btn_action...
where did  I go wrong..??

I have tried many solutions but could not get any answer...

below are html  and javascript code. I am using all the required jquery resources.

```
<form method="post" id="user_form">
  <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
  <h4 class="modal-title"></i> Add User
  </h4>
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;
 </button>

  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
  <div class="form-group">
<label>Enter User Name</label>
<input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" class="form-control" required />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Enter User Email
</label>
<input type="email" name="user_email" id="user_email" class="form-control" required />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Enter User Password</label>
<input type="password" name="user_password" id="user_password" class="form-control" required />
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
  <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" />
  <input type="hidden" name="btn_action" id="btn_action" />
  <input type="submit" name ="action" id= "action" class="btn btn-primary" 
   value="Add" />
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="mo  
  dal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
</form>

//script code:

$(document).on('submit', '#user_form', function(event){
event.preventDefault();
$('#action').attr('disabled','disabled');
var form_data = $('#user_form').serialize();
alert(form_data);
// console.log(form_data)
$.ajax({
url:"user_action.php",
method:"POST",
data:form_data,
success:function(data)

{
$('#user_form')[0].reset();
$('#userModal').modal('hide');
$('#alert_action').fadeIn().html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+data+'</div>');
$('#action').attr('disabled', false);## Heading ##

}
});
});
```

```js
<script>

    $(document).on('click','#add_button',function(){
    $('#action').val("Insert");

    $('.modal-title').text("Add User");

    });

    $(document).on('submit', '#user_form', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();


    var form_data = $('#user_form').serialize();
    alert(form_data);//not returning the required values

    $.ajax({
    url:"user_action.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:form_data,
    contentType:false,
    processData:false,
    success:function(data)

    {
    $('#user_form')[0].reset();
    $('#userModal').modal('hide');
    $('#alert_action').fadeIn().html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+data+'</div>');
    $('#action').attr('disabled', false);
    userdataTable.ajax.reload();
    }
    });
    });





    });


    </script>
```

```html
<!-- form -->
<form method="post" id="user_form">
  <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
  <h4 class="modal-title"></i> Add User</h4>
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
  <div class="form-group">
<label>Enter User Name</label>
<input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" class="form-control" required />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Enter User Email</label>
<input type="email" name="user_email" id="user_email" class="form-control" required />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Enter User Password</label>
<input type="password" name="user_password" id="user_password" class="form-control" required />
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
  <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" />
  <input type="hidden" name="btn_action" id="btn_action" />
  <input type="submit" name ="action" id= "action" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add" />
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="mo  dal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
</form>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `console.log(form_data);` returns me everything except `user_id` and `btn_action`, because there are no values ?

Comment: https://www.webslesson.info/2017/11/php-mysql-inventory-management-system-using-ajax.html  : I am referencing this site for the code and this code is working fine for him ... please have a look in user.php and user_action.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two hidden inputs have no values attached to them so you will not find them in the serialized value, add some values to the inputs directly in the html or with javascript

```
 <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="some user_id"/>
 <input type="hidden" name="btn_action" id="btn_action" value="some btn_action"/>
```